# How to Test Api In Rails Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec-rails

I'm new to rails testing,i want to test my rails controller api. 
I using gems **rails-rspec** ,**capybara** and **database-cleaner** like this in my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

And in my spec folder i create a controller and create a **user_controller_spec.rb** inside my api folder and want to test create a user with valid parameters and write a code like this:

```
RSpec.describe "API V1 Users", type: 'request' do
  describe "POST /api/v1/users" do
    context "with valid parameters" do
      let(:valid_params) do
        { 
          fname: "Riya",
          lname: "******",
          email: "*******.com",
          password: "",
          contact: "2144333",
          country_code:"91",
          address: "Sector 63",
          city: "Noida",
          state: "UP",
          country: "India",
          zipcode: "23001",
          role: "***",
          image: ""
        }
      end

  it "creates a new user" do
    expect { post "/api/v1/users", params: valid_params}
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)  # it's use for code 200 
  end

  it "creates a user with the correct attributes" do
    post "/api/v1/users", params: valid_params 
    expect(User.last).to have_attributes valid_params
  end
end

context "with invalid parameters" do
   # testing for validation failures is just as important!
   # ...
end
  end
end
```

But it gives me error :

```
Failure/Error: expect(User.last).to have_attributes valid_params expected nil to respond to :fname, :lname, :email, :password, :contact
```

Comment: Please show controller action and model validations

Comment: Looks like your params are invalid and User is not saved into database

Comment: `post "/api/v1/users", params: valid_params ` your post action doesn't create user which cause User.last  to be `nil` debug your controller action.

Comment: it creates a user and return a user with id 1 But when i check my database i don't see that user and error is

Error: expect(User.last).to have_attributes valid_params

Comment: expected #<User id: 1, fname: "Ri", lname: "Ra", contact: "2144", address: "Sector 63", city: "Noida",...ty_code: nil, country_code: "91"> to have attributes {:email => "xxx@xxx.com", :password => "123456", :fname => "Riya", :lname => "", :role => "", :...ddress => "xx", :city => "xx", :state => "x", :country => "x", :zipcode => "x", :image => ""} but had attributes {:email => "xxx@xxx.com", :password => nil, :fname => "Riya", :lname => "Rajput", :role => "business", :conta...dress => "Sector 63", :city => "Noida", :state => "UP", :country => "India", :zipcode => "23", :image => nil}

Comment: lname and role at least not match

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that your post query create an user you can write it like this:

```
expect { post "/api/v1/users", params: valid_params}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
```

It test if a user is added to the database.